# Sending object form angularjs to API .net core is always with id=0

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to send an object from angularjs to API .net core. Everything is ok but id, in angular it is with it's value but in API it is always 0 (zero). every id in the object is 0 (zero).

The code from angularjs:

```
vm.editReservation = function editReservation() {
    reservationService.editReservation(vm.reservation).then(function(result) {
            toastr.options = { "positionClass": "toast-top-full-width" };
            toastr.success("Ruajtja u krye me sukses");
    }).catch(function (response) {
        toastr.options = { "positionClass": "toast-top-full-width" };
        toastr.error(response.message);
    });
};
```

The code from API .net core:

```
[HttpPost("editReservation")]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditReservation([FromBody] Models.Reservation reservation)
{
    Models.Reservation modelReservation;
    ReservationDuration modelReservationDuration;
    ReservationLocation modelReservationLocation;
    Person client;
    TaxRate taxRate;
    string textMessage;
    try
    {
        //some code here
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

I expect that reservation.id = {any number} but the actual it is {0}

From Angularjs:

[image: From Angularjs]

To API:

[image: To API]

Comment: Looks like it's not binding your object and you're getting the default integer value of 0. Look to your json structure and verify that it maps 1:1 with your c# model.

Comment: I added two images the first is the object sent from angular, the second is the object accepted from API.

Comment: It's too many times happened to me. It can be from your Api model properties and encapsulation. Check if your mentioned property doesn't set to **Internal** in encapsulation model. Sincerely

Comment: That solved my problem, it was with ID protected like:  public virtual TId Id { get;  protected set; }